# Investigating cause of 000 returned error code from cURL in bash script

Tags: bash, curl, error-handling

I'm using cURL to check links for uptime in a bash script like this:

`curl -Lo /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' $link`

Where `link="http://deadlink/"` for example.

It returns 000 cos it's a dead link which is fine, but whenever I get a 000 response from cURL (since it could be for many reasons), I'd like to apply some logic to find out what's happening there. For instance, is it because connection refused, timeout, ssl failure, etc?

I assume the best way would some way to isolate the error code directly from cURL and apply tests to it using IF statements. That would be fine, so the closest I've got to extracting the error code from cURL **by itself** is this:

```
failState=$(curl -Ss $link; echo "error code is $?" )
echo $failState
```

Which nicely returns:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: brokenlink
error code is 6
```

How do I get the "6" into a variable?

Comment: BTW, this is discussed in [BashFAQ #2](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002).

Comment: As another aside, if you only want *one* piece of output and don't need to distinguish specific non-successful HTTP status values, consider using `--fail` so curl will set `$?` to 22 should there be a HTTP status of 400 or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign `$?` to another variable right after assigning curl's output to `failState`.

```
failState=$(curl -Ss "$link") exitCode=$?
```

Comment: (1) Consider quoting `"$link"`; (2) Consider putting the exit-status collection on the same line as the command setting it so logging or other code changes are less likely to unintentionally modify the status before it's collected.